# appendChild doesn't work when using drag and drop

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop

I would like to move the content of a box into the other box using drag and drop. The content of the same box should not be inserted into the same box.

This is what I have tried:

```js
// Drag and the drop the items
const elements = document.querySelectorAll('#box1, #box2');

for (let element of elements) {
  // Allow the drop 
  element.addEventListener("dragover", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
  }, false);

  element.addEventListener('drop', (evt) => {
    evt.preventDefault();
    const data = evt.dataTransfer.getData("text/plain");
    console.log(data);
    document.appendChild(data);
  });
}
```

```css
.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
#box1 {
  background: red;
}
#box2 {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div draggable="true" class="box" id="box1"><strong>1</strong></div>
<div draggable="true" class="box" id="box2"><strong>2</strong></div>
```

Issue: Nothing gets inserted and I get the error *Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.*

Answer (score 0):

appendChild always works it's just how you use it

```
const data = evt.dataTransfer.getData("text/plain");
    console.log(data);
    document.appendChild(data);
```

Is data an HTML element? It looks like it's just text, I think you meant `evt.target` or something

If not just make a new element and set it's contents to date then attend the new element

Also I don't think you can append it to document directly, I think you need to do document.body or other node